# Remove Sharing Restriction

Tags: permissions, windows-11, sharing

I've been trying to share a folder on my machine with my wife who is on the same LAN. I'm in Windows 11 preview. I don't understand why this is so silly/difficult. I finally figured out how to remove Windows demand that my wife enter a userid and pwd, but now I'm getting this message:

[image]

I want anybody on this network to access all files/printers I share w/o passwords of other security measures. All the Windows help I can find gives vague general info rather than what I expect in a step by step manner. I figured that sharing would be done with an expert system as I said, step by step.

Comment: Folder Sharing can be enabled and disabled in the Properties of the Folder:  Sharing and Security.  Look there.

Comment: It doesn't. When I click to show all shared items on my computer a whole raft of them show up just as expected however none of them are accessible from other devices - PCs, laptop or iPad. Yesterday when I posted the OP, I could see the shared computer on the network . Today it's disappeared although the shared folders show shared when I click to display them on the computer that has the resources.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with your OS.  What I suggested works here on any of my machines. Tested.  You can put a batch file on each persons's machine with the NET USE command to map and to provide authentication and then they just click on the batch file.